# New to Node and having trouble with the Youtube Data API

Tags: node.js, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Using Node.js for the first time and working with the Youtube Data API. I can't quite get the data I want from the API when I make a request to it. This is what the data coming back from the API is supposed to look like:

```
/**
 * API response
 */
{
  "kind": "youtube#commentThreadListResponse",
  "etag": "\"VPWTmrH7dFmi4s1RqrK4tLejnRI/yVL3QyyDwJFkFNOcCd4KZCcTFDw\"",
  "nextPageToken": "QURTSl9pMlQySG1zcHRKb0dNZ3dWdlYtcUhyRDFDVlJXaHFmdVFiMUlaUFJfTTNjdTFpQzFNWUNuWjhBY0d2ZV8tTGR2aHFXRXRJVDZRQVpRM0YzNndWVXlQVFNwOU94UVFCWVd2empIVUlGdHlFR25keU8=",
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 20,
    "resultsPerPage": 20
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "youtube#commentThread",
      "etag": "\"VPWTmrH7dFmi4s1RqrK4tLejnRI/OqxtT8nFAjcFFrHa4DbZrY_NItM\"",
      "id": "z13bwzmokuzcxtcqn04cclqbiozixldh21o"
    },
    {
      "kind": "youtube#commentThread",
      "etag": "\"VPWTmrH7dFmi4s1RqrK4tLejnRI/1B_usKd_ZpCLxG5l5nL7QfUtG3o\"",
      "id": "z13puhijunbzytdcn22lstwptmybyzwdl"
    },
    {
      "kind": "youtube#commentThread",
      "etag": "\"VPWTmrH7dFmi4s1RqrK4tLejnRI/h8sS5KTOFa7CQWU5Je2Fp5UQ0bk\"",
      "id": "z13dfbwzjyrpiznqc04cgjlpbyn0wtaiqpw0k"
    },
    {
      "kind": "youtube#commentThread",
      "etag": "\"VPWTmrH7dFmi4s1RqrK4tLejnRI/FQEl6XU95FHiM1ijRxC5fqngmqk\"",
      "id": "z12atro51wfhzvmp104cihfytveyshbr4s40k"
    },
    { ...........AND SO ON
```

I then use the following code in an attempt to console.log() this data from the youtube API

```
var DATABASE = youtube.commentThreads.list( 
{ 'videoId': '7YcW25PHnAA', 'part': 'id, replies'}, function(err, data){ 
  if(err){ 
    console.error('Error: ' + err);
   } 
});

var resp = JSON.stringify(DATABASE); 
console.log(resp);
```

But this is my output instead:

```
{
    "uri": {
        "protocol": "https:",
        "slashes": true,
        "auth": null,
        "host": "www.googleapis.com",
        "port": null,
        "hostname": "www.googleapis.com",
        "hash": null,
        "search": "?videoId=7YcW25PHnAA&part=id%2C%20replies&key=AIzaSyDTTnj4HncXQCM3U-9XUvHyIf7kE9f2ZUk",
        "query": "videoId=7YcW25PHnAA&part=id%2C%20replies&key=AIzaSyDTTnj4HncXQCM3U-9XUvHyIf7kE9f2ZUk",
        "pathname": "/youtube/v3/commentThreads",
        "path": "/youtube/v3/commentThreads?videoId=7YcW25PHnAA&part=id%2C%20replies&key=AIzaSyDTTnj4HncXQCM3U-9XUvHyIf7kE9f2ZUk",
        "href": "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?videoId=7YcW25PHnAA&part=id%2C%20replies&key=AIzaSyDTTnj4HncXQCM3U-9XUvHyIf7kE9f2ZUk"
    },
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {
        "User-Agent": "google-api-nodejs-client/0.10.0",
        "host": "www.googleapis.com",
        "accept": "application/json"
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You will get the data in the callback, not after the function call